# Show notification through browser in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight, notifications

I'm creating a Silverlight application which can push notification to other users and I want to display the message to the Browser (my users use IE and Firefox to access my website). I noted that some web browsers such as Chrome, Firefox, IE support display Notification when we access to websites which has notification feature. So how can I do this for both Firefox and IE like this? I'm trying to find the solution but due to my quite bad English I still couldn't. Thanks alot.
[image: Firefox notification]

Comment: You would primarily use javascript to send these notification to the browser. start by looking here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API. I would suggest implementing it on the page hosting the silverlight application and have the application call the javascript that triggers the notification.

Comment: @Nkosi First, thanks for your help. However, the problem here is I want the notification work well both Firefox and IE and Notification API seem doesn't support IE. Can you show me any better way?

Comment: That's the only one that comes up when searching. Edge seems to support it but not the older browsers like IE.

Comment: @Nkosi I've found some APIs that is supposed support IE but it still didn't work on my PC. And for some reasons my feature must work well both Firefox and IE, therefore, that's my really big challenge.